# Unable to replicate post_filter query in elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

The query I would like to replicate in DSL is as below:

```
GET /_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "destination":"singapore"
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "tag_ids":[
                     "tag_luxury"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "max_price":{
         "max":{
            "field":"price_range_from.SGD"
         }
      },
      "min_price":{
         "min":{
            "field":"price_range_from.SGD"
         }
      }
   },
   "post_filter":{
      "range":{
         "price_range_from.SGD":{
            "gte":0.0,
            "lte":100.0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The above query

1. Matches terms - `destination` and `tags_ids`
2. Aggregates to result to find the max price from field `price_range_from.SGD`
3. Applies another post_filter to subset the result set within price limits

**It works perfectly well in the Elastic/Kibana console.**

I replicated the above query in elasticsearch-dsl as below:

```
    es_query = []
    es_query.append(Q("term", destination="singapore"))
    es_query.append(Q("terms", tag_ids=["tag_luxury"]))
    final_query = Q("bool", must=es_query)
    
    es_conn = ElasticSearch.instance().get_client()
    dsl_client = DSLSearch(using=es_conn, index=index).get_dsl_client()
    dsl_client.query = final_query
    dsl_client.aggs.metric("min_price", "min", field="price_range_from.SGD")
    dsl_client.aggs.metric("max_price", "max", field="price_range_from.SGD")
    q = Q("range", **{"price_range_from.SGD":{"gte": 0.0, "lte": 100.0}})
    dsl_client.post_filter(q)
    
    print(dsl_client.to_dict())
    response = dsl_client.execute()
    print(response.to_dict().get("hits", {}))
```

Although the aggregations are correct, **products beyond the price range are also being returned**. There is no error returned but it seems like the post_filter query is not applied.

I dived in the `dsl_client` object to see whether my query is being captured correctly. I see only the `query` and `aggs` but don't see the `post_filter` part in the object. The query when converted to a dictionary using `dsl_client.to_dict()` is as below -

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "destination":"singapore"
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "tag_ids":[
                     "tag_luxury"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "min_price":{
         "min":{
            "field":"price_range_from.SGD"
         }
      },
      "max_price":{
         "max":{
            "field":"price_range_from.SGD"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-assign the `dsl_client` like:

`dsl_client = dsl_client.post_filter(q)`